# Flutter sms_autofill doesn't always read the OTP automatically

Tags: flutter, dart, autofill

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sms_autofill/sms_autofill.dart';
import './../../widgets/color_loader.dart';
import './../../models/login_api_response_model.dart';
import './../../services/Authentication/authentication_service.dart';
import './../../models/enum_models.dart';
import './login_error_page.dart';

class ValidateOtp extends StatefulWidget {
  final String mobileNumber;
  ValidateOtp({@required this.mobileNumber});
  @override
  _ValidateOtpState createState() => _ValidateOtpState();
}

class _ValidateOtpState extends State<ValidateOtp> {
  final SmsAutoFill _autoFill = SmsAutoFill();
  bool verifactionFailed = false;
  Future<LoginApiResponseModel> response;
  LoginApiResponseModel loginApiResponseModel;
  bool isInit = true;
  bool resendOtp = false;
  String otp;

  void fetchOtp() {
    print('setState fetchOtp');
    response = AuthenticationService.generateOtp(widget.mobileNumber)
        .then((value) => loginApiResponseModel = value);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _listenOTP();
    fetchOtp();
    super.initState();
  }


  void _listenOTP() async {
    await SmsAutoFill().listenForCode;
  }

  validateOtp(String otp) {
    print('Code received $otp');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    SmsAutoFill().unregisterListener();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('${_autoFill.getAppSignature}');
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: response,
        builder: (context, dataSnapShopt) {
          if (dataSnapShopt.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: ColorLoader(),
            );
          } else if (dataSnapShopt.error != null) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Something went wrong..'),
            );
          } else {
            return loginApiResponseModel.status == 'fail'
                ? LoginErrorPage(
                    errorMessage: 'Invalid Mobile number!',
                    errorType: ErrorType.InvalidMobileNumber,
                  )
                : Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: PinFieldAutoFill(
                            autofocus: true,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            codeLength: 6,
                            onCodeChanged: (value) {
                              if (value.length == 6) {
                                print(' onCodeChanged');
                                otp = value;
                              }
                            },
                  
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                          onPressed: () => validateOtp(otp),
                          label: Text('Confirm'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text('Didn\'t receive OTP? '),
                          FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                resendOtp = !resendOtp;
                              });
                              fetchOtp();
                            },
                            child: Text('RESEND'),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hi,
I am using `sms_autofill 1.2.3` to autofill the OTP.
my flutter application is able to read the OTP automatically but not always, Like when I make some change and do hot reload or even after running flutter run again sometimes it doesn't read the code am I missing something?
I am using sms_autofill 1.2.3 to autofill the OTP.
my flutter application is able to read the OTP automatically but not always, Like when I make some change and do hot reload or even after running flutter run again sometimes it doesn't read the code am I missing something?

Comment: Can i get the code as how you implemented the sms_autofill with the http?

Comment: @Niroop, Code is attached with the description. Do you need anything else?

Comment: my bad! i just made some mistake in my end

Comment: would you please tell us your mistake because I am also getting this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing this on Android, make sure that you've added the hash or signature code at the end of your message to identify your app as mentioned in the [plugin's doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63517814/flutter-sms-autofill-doesnt-always-read-the-otp-automatically). The [hash](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify) should correspond to the your app's keystore signature.